# QT Android app should start just after android boot log

Tags: android, c++, qt, imx6

We are trying to create a QT 5.7 application for Android M6.
**Our requirement is, our GUI application(QT 5.7 application for Android M6) should start after the "android" boot logo.**
That is before home screen, we need to start/lunch our app.

Could you please suggest a method how can we make this happen?

**Development Environment:**
OS: Andriod M6
Board: iMX6q-Sabre Auto
QT Version - QT 5.7

Comment: that's not Android development, but Linux development. You can't start Android app before Android loaded.

Comment: I need to start QT Android app after android loading, but before home screen..

Comment: then I can suggest defining your application as a home screen, and setting it as default home screen

Comment: Could you please give some reference in developing same on QT Android app.

Comment: I unfortunately have no idea about QT development, only Java and some C# (Xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this documentation:
[Boot to Qt](http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-about-b2qt.html)

> Boot to Qt for embedded Linux is built using the tools and resources from the Yocto Project, and is based on Yocto's reference distribution (Poky).